# Ambiguous use of 'init(contentsOfURL:)' in swift 4.1

Tags: swift

I use Swift 4.1 and XCode 9.3

```
var upsList = [Any]()

func loadUpsValues () {
    print("loadUpsValues")
    let upsFileAsURL = URL(string: "Upslist.txt")
    //    Original Objective C Call was: NSMutableArray *ListUpsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:upsFile];
    //
    let upsList = NSArray(contentsOfURL:upsFileAsURL! )
}
```

I get an error: `Ambiguous use of 'init(contentsOfURL:)'`
and it seems that the source for `NSArray` comes from the same foundation definition:

I have twice:

```
1 Found this candidate (Foundation.NSArray)
2 Found this candidate (Foundation.NSArray)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are there even an init called `contentsOfURL` it doesn't appear in any documentation?

Comment: On a side note, stop using `(NS)Type`s in **Swift**. Use the Swift types (e.g. `String`, `Array` `Dictionary` `Int`).

Answer (score 1):

This error is because `[NS(Mutable)Array arrayWithContentsOfURL:];` does not exists in Swift.

For swift the `NSArray` initialiser has been changed to be more 'swifty' so it became:

```
NSArray(contentsOf:)
```

As seen [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/NSArray.swift#L628).

---

So changing your last line, the code should run as expected, i.e:

```
let upsList = NSArray(contentsOf: upsFileAsURL!)
```

**Edit:**

Going with the comment from @nayem. Assuming your text file is a collection of lines, you could change your code to work without relying on NS based objects like so:

```
func loadUpsValues () {
    do {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Upslist", withExtension: "txt") else { return }

        let data = try String(contentsOf: url)
        let upsList = data.components(separatedBy: NSCharacterSet.newlines)

        ...
    } catch {
        /* handle error */
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I will keep your Idea for the gard line. Finally here is a line of code which made the error desapear:         let upsList:NSArray = NSArray(contentsOf:upsFileAsURL! )! and works properly

Comment: Thanks to you Harry and also to Maku. Have a nice day !!

Comment: Same for Vollan and Nayem

Answer (score 0):

Look at this solution:

You have declared once the upsList, why do you declare it again as a *let*
This solution works.

```
    var upsList = NSArray()

func loadUpsValues () {
    print("loadUpsValues")
    let upsFileAsURL = URL(string: "Upslist.txt")
    //    Original Objective C Call was: NSMutableArray *ListUpsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:upsFile];
    //
    upsList = NSArray(contentsOf: upsFileAsURL! ) ?? NSArray()
}
```